# Grand canonical potential for a Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have a question about the FD and BE grand canonical potential. We derived the expression for both cases, but probably the expressions must be wrong.

$$J_{FD}=kT\sum_i\ln\left(1+ e^{-\beta(\epsilon_i - \mu)}\right)$$ for Fermi-Dirac.

$$J_{BE}= -kT\sum_i\ln\left(1 - e^{-\beta(\epsilon_i - \mu)}\right)$$ for Bose-Einstein.

But shouldn't it be the other way around, meaning plus sign below and negative sign above?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: because when you derive the grand canonical partition functions, for the bose einstein you have an expression on power -1 which means when you try to find the potential witht he formula -ktlY,  you get a 2nd minus, which will result in a plus

Comment: Are you referring to the minus sign before the $kT$, or the minus sign in $1 \pm e^{-\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}$? My initial assumption was that you meant the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grand Canonical Partition function look like
$$\ln \mathcal{Z}=\pm\sum_i\ln(1\pm e^{\beta(\mu-E_i)})$$
where the $\pm$ sign means $+$ for fermions and $-$ for bosons.
$$\Phi_G=-k_BT\ln\mathcal{Z}=\mp k_BT\sum_i \ln(1\pm e^{\beta(\mu-E_i)})$$

So indeed your expression should have flipped sign.

Comment: Exactly! But then it comes this 2nd problem in my script.  Later we try to derive the grand canonical partition function  for the case of continues energy/momentum values. If i make the change, then i should get a minus by then end for the FD case, while the professor, has no minus. What should i do???

Comment: how can that be? I have a plus there, not a minus. That's who we derived it

Comment: Ah, that's alright.

Comment: $Y_{FD} = \Pi_i (1+ e^{-\beta (\epsilon_i - \mu)})$ for the fermi dirac grand canonical partition function.   $Y_{BE} = \Pi_i (1- e^{-\beta (\epsilon_i - \mu)})^{-1}$ Bose einstein. If you use this expressions, you will get the minus for FD and plus for BE

Comment: @imbAF Can you show your calculation? The one you are talking of in your first comment